# My label is not displaying with the correct combination

Tags: java

When I run my program, the correct message does not display after entering the correct combination. For some reason, the error message displays no matter what combination is entered. My code is below. Please help me if you can.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;


public class Program3 extends JFrame 
{
    // JLabel that displays header on application window
    private JLabel instructionsJLabel;

    // JSpinners for combination lock
    private JSpinner oneJSpinner;
    private JSpinner twoJSpinner;
    private JSpinner threeJSpinner;
    private JSpinner fourJSpinner;
    private JSpinner fiveJSpinner;

    // JLabel for buttons
    private JButton openJButton;
    private JButton resetJButton;

    // Message area
    private JLabel displayJLabel;

    // no-argument constructor
    public Program3() 
    {
        createUserInterface();

    }
        // create and position GUI components; register event handlers
        private void createUserInterface()

    {
        // get content pane for attaching GUI components
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout( null );

        //set up instructionsJLabel
        instructionsJLabel = new JLabel();
        instructionsJLabel.setBounds( 10, 5, 200, 30 );
        instructionsJLabel.setText( "Combination Lock" );
        instructionsJLabel.setFont( 
        new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16 ) );
        contentPane.add( instructionsJLabel );

        //set up JSpinner one
      oneJSpinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel( 1, 1, 9, 1 ) );
      oneJSpinner.setBounds( 16, 50, 30, 20);
      oneJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
      contentPane.add( oneJSpinner );

        //set up JSpinner two
      twoJSpinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel( 1, 1, 9, 1) );
      twoJSpinner.setBounds( 66, 50, 30, 20);
      twoJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
      contentPane.add( twoJSpinner );

        //set up JSpinner three
      threeJSpinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel( 1, 1, 9, 1  ) );
      threeJSpinner.setBounds( 116, 50, 30, 20);
      threeJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
      contentPane.add( threeJSpinner );

        //set up JSpinner four
      fourJSpinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel( 1, 1, 9, 1) );
      fourJSpinner.setBounds( 166, 50, 30, 20);
      fourJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
      contentPane.add( fourJSpinner );

        //set up JSpinner five
      fiveJSpinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel( 1, 1, 9, 1 ) );
      fiveJSpinner.setBounds( 216, 50, 30, 20);
      fiveJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
      contentPane.add( fiveJSpinner );

        // set up openJButton and register its event handler
        openJButton = new JButton();
        openJButton.setBounds( 16, 100, 80, 25 );
        openJButton.setText( "Open" );
        openJButton.setFont( 
        new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12 ) );
        contentPane.add( openJButton );
        openJButton.addActionListener( 

        new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
        {
            // event handler called when user clicks openJButton
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
            {
                openJButtonActionPerformed( event );
            }      
        } // end anonymous inner class

        ); // end call to addActionListener

        // set up resetJButton and register its event handler
        resetJButton = new JButton();
        resetJButton.setBounds( 166, 100, 80, 25 );
        resetJButton.setText( "Reset" );
        resetJButton.setFont( 
        new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12 ) );
        contentPane.add( resetJButton );
        resetJButton.addActionListener( 

        new ActionListener() // anonymous inner class
        {
            // event handler called when user clicks resetJButton
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
            {
                resetJButtonActionPerformed( event );
            }      
        } // end anonymous inner class

        ); // end call to addActionListener

        // set up displayJLabel
        displayJLabel = new JLabel();
        displayJLabel.setBounds( 16, 150, 300, 25 );
        displayJLabel.setText( "" );
        contentPane.add( displayJLabel );       

        setTitle("Locker");
        setSize (300, 250);
        setVisible(true);

    }// } end method createUserInterface

   // method called when user clicks openJButton
   private int combination=26611;

   private void openJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
      Integer one = ( Integer )oneJSpinner.getValue();
      Integer two = ( Integer )twoJSpinner.getValue()*10;
      Integer three = ( Integer )threeJSpinner.getValue()*100;
      Integer four = ( Integer )fourJSpinner.getValue()*1000;
      Integer five = ( Integer )fiveJSpinner.getValue()*10000;

      combination = one + two + three + four + five;

      if(combination==26611)
      {
        displayJLabel.setText ( "Combination Opened" );
      }

      else {
        displayJLabel.setText ( "Wrong Combination. Hit Reset and Try Again" ); 
      } // end else
    } // end method openJButtonActionPerformed

  private void resetJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
      {
     oneJSpinner.setValue ( 5 );
     twoJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
     threeJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
     fourJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
     fiveJSpinner.setValue( 5 );
     displayJLabel.setText( "" );
      }

//
public static void main ( String[] args )
   {
    Program3 application = new Program3();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

   } // end method main

} // end class Program 3.
```

Comment: What number are you entering on the spinners?  Is it 11662?  Because that's the number that your code checks for.

Comment: @TerryStorm why don't you just correct your answer, instead of deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Output the combination you calculated based on the user's input. This will help you debug the application and you will notice, why the error message always pops up:

```
combination = one + two + three + four + five;
int expected = 26611;

System.out.println("User input: " + combination + ", expected: " + expected);

if(combination==expected)
{
  displayJLabel.setText ( "Combination Opened" );
}
```